# React doesn't rerender on an array state update

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, material-ui

I'm trying to make 3 button controls to open and close 3 corresponding menu lists. Material-UI is the UI framework I'm currently using. Here is the code:

```
const Filters = () => {

    const [anchors, setAnchors] = useState([null, null, null])

    const handleClick = (event, index) => {
        const arr = anchors
        arr[index] = event.target
        setAnchors(arr)    
    }

    const handleClose = (index) => {
        const arr = anchors
        arr[index] = null
        setAnchors(arr)  
    }

    return(
        <div id="top-filters">
            <div className="controls">
                <Button onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, 0)}>Sort By</Button>
                <Button onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, 1)}>Price</Button>
                <Button onClick={(event) => handleClick(event, 2)}>Delivery Fees</Button>
            </div>
        {
            console.log({anchors})
        }
            <Menu key={1}
                anchorEl={anchors[0]} 
                open={Boolean(anchors[0])} 
                onClose={() => handleClose(0)} 
                keepMounted
            >
                <MenuItem>
                    <ListItemText primary="By Rating" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>

            <Menu key={2}
                anchorEl={anchors[1]} 
                open={Boolean(anchors[1])} 
                onClose={() => handleClose(1)} 
                keepMounted            
            >
                <MenuItem>
                    <Slider defaultValue={25} marks={marks} step={25} />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>

            <Menu key={3}
                anchorEl={anchors[2]} 
                open={Boolean(anchors[2])} 
                onClose={() => handleClose(2)} 
                keepMounted            
            >
                <MenuItem>
                    <ListItemText primary="By Delivery Fees" />
                </MenuItem>
            </Menu>

            <FormControl className="search-bar-filter">
                <Icon>search</Icon>
                <StyledInput classes={{ root: classes.root }} name="search" type="search" placeholder="Search" disableUnderline />
            </FormControl>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Filters
```

I checked the values update in console, they look fine, but I'm not sure why React won't rerender the page (when I click the buttons, nothing happens but anchors state is updated). Thanks for help.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

What you are doing there is a mutation:

```
arr[index] = event.target
```

You should avoid mutation when updating your state. Because if you mutate your state React can not understand your state has changed. You can use methods like `map`, `filter` or any other method which do not mutate your state.

```
const handleClick = (event, index) => {
  setAnchors((prev) =>
    prev.map((el, i) => {
      if (i !== index) {
        return el;
      }

      return event.target;
    })
  );
};
```

or if you like a concise one:

```
const handleClick = (event, index) => {
  setAnchors((prev) => prev.map((el, i) => (i !== index ? el : event.target)));
};
```

The spread syntax can be used for non-nested arrays, but if you are working on nested arrays and changing the nested values just be careful since spread syntax creates shallow copies. This is why I like to to use methods like `map` most of the time.

If you don't want to map all over the array (some prefers this) `Object.assign` and spread syntax can be used together.

```
const handleClick = (event, index) => {
  setAnchors((prev) => Object.assign([], { ...prev, [index]: event.target }));
};
```

Update:

As I explained before, spread syntax only makes shallow copies.

> Note: Spread syntax effectively goes one level deep while copying an
> array. Therefore, it may be unsuitable for copying multidimensional
> arrays, as the following example shows. (The same is true with
> Object.assign() and spread syntax.)

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

This means nested values keep the same references as the original ones. So, if you change something for the new array (or object) it also changes the original one.

```js
const arr = [
  { id: 0, name: "foo" },
  { id: 1, name: "bar" },
  { id: 2, name: "baz" },
];

const newArr = [...arr];

newArr[0].name = "something else";

console.log("newArr", newArr);
console.log("original arr", arr);
```

As you can see our original array also changed. Actually, this isn't a nested array but we are changing a nested property for the array element. Maybe this is a better example for nested arrays, but the example above is more realistic.

```js
const arr = [["foo", "bar"], [1,2]];

const newArr = [...arr];

newArr[0][0] = "fizz";

console.log(newArr);
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Hi devserkan, thanks for your help, Your code also works and I feel like it's safer to go with your approach. But can you please explain more about what could go wrong with spread syntax on a nested array?

Comment: I added an example to show how spread syntax changes the original one if it is used on a nested array. Again, for your case, it is ok to use spread syntax . Just know that it only makes shallow copies and don't use it for nested arrays, objects. I prefer not to use it at all.

Comment: Thank you so much, you let me learn more than what I just asked

Answer (score 7):

You are wrongly updating the state.
`const arr = anchors` is not the correct way to clone the anchors. You need to use `...` operator.

```
    const handleClick = (event, index) => {
        const arr = [... anchors]
        arr[index] = event.target
        setAnchors(arr)    
    }

    const handleClose = (index) => {
        const arr = [... anchors]
        arr[index] = null
        setAnchors(arr)  
    }
```

Comment: That is the reason! Thanks for your quick response. Can you please explain more on why my code wouldn't work? Thanks again

Comment: react uses "shallow" comparison of state and props to determine if the component must rerender. Arrays are reference types. When using const arr = anchors, and then setting state to arr, its the same reference to that array, thus it wont rerender. using the spread operator, const arr = [...anchors], causes arr to have a different reference to anchors. Then, when setting state to that array reference, shallow comparison will return that they are different, and react will rerender the component. I can create codesandbox showing the difference if you need further help.

Comment: as i mentioned, `const arr = anchors` is not the correct way. once you are trying to update arr value like arr[index] = ..., it means, you are also updating the anchors. and you know you can't update the state value directly

Comment: @Gandzal You gave me a very clear explaination, I got your point, thanks a lot!

Comment: this is often what trips people, at least people like me who are not sure what javascript or typescript handles references and array assignments and such. thank you.

Comment: Lot of thanks brother <3