# have array of objects stored in useState. doesn't update when using the updater function

Tags: reactjs

This is a simplified example of some code I have.

I have a some state, that stores an array of objects

```
const [characters,setCharacters] = useState([
   {
     val:1,
     bool:false
   },
   {
     val:2,
     bool:false
   },
   {
     val:3,
     bool:false
   },
])
```

I want to update one of the `bool`'s to true. I then do

```
setCharacters(prev => {
  prev[2].bool = true
  return prev
})
```

But it doesn't work. Can anyone explain why?

Comment: Don't _mutate_ state. You're returning the same array, containing all of the same objects, you got given.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React doesn't rerender on an array state update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982593/react-doesnt-rerender-on-an-array-state-update)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set a new reference. That is how react detect updates for state variables which are objects.

```
setCharacters(prev => {
  let prev2=[...prev]
  prev2[2] ={ ...prev2[2], bool : true};
  return prev2;
})
```

Above code, creates a new reference for the array and the object at `2` index.

Answer (score 0):

This will generate `too many re-renders` because you have called to times set function which is actually `componentDidUpdate().`

In this case you have to use useEffect hook to wrap the second set function.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

const Test = () => {
    const [characters,setCharacters] = useState([
        {
          val:1,
          bool:false
        },
        {
          val:2,
          bool:false
        },
        {
          val:3,
          bool:false
        },
     ])
     // useEffect - component life-cycle method (componentDidUpdate)
     useEffect(() => {
     // your update functionality
        setCharacters(prev => {
            prev[2].bool = true
            return prev
          })
     },[]); // empty dependency array to render the UI only at first
    return (
        <div>
            {
                characters.map((item, i) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={i}>
                            <p>{item.val}</p>
                            <p>{item.bool ? "true":"false"}</p>
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )
}

export default Test;
```

I this way you can update the state while page first time rendering.

**Your Initial Value for prev[2] was false; But see in image below that your prev[2] = true as you were expecting.**

***Here is the output on browser:***

[image]

Comment: Further more, componentDidUpdate is a lifecycle method in React when we use class base component. But in case of functional component You have to use useEffect hook.

Comment: You can learn more from this: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/reactjs-componentdidupdate-method/#:~:text=The%20componentDidUpdate()%20method%20allows,component%20changes%20are%20coded%20here.