# React updating useState array not causing element refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am unable to trigger the component to update when the viaList state is changed. If anyone could help, please <3

I don't want to append these children if possible.

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function BookingForm() {
  const [viaList, setViaList] = useState([]);

  function addViaLocation() {
    const arr = viaList;

    arr.push(
    <li key={uuidv4()}>
      <label className="form-label">
        Via Location
      </label>
    </li>)

    setViaList(arr);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addViaLocation} className="button-standard primary" type="button">
        Add Additional Location
      </button>
      <ul>{viaList.length > 0 && viaList.map(item => item)}</ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default BookingForm;
```

- Separating the functionality into a separate component
- Triggering the update using props
- Regular DOM stuff (appending doesn't fit our use case)

Comment: Don't use `arr.push`, create a new array like this: `[...arr, newElement]`. Even better to use set state like this: `setViaList(prev => [...prev, newElement])`.

Comment: Also I wouldn't store JSX in an array if you can avoid it (which you can), instead just store an object containing the information you need and then turn it to HTML/JSX in the `return` (within `viaList.map`, which currently does nothing).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React doesn't rerender on an array state update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64982593/react-doesnt-rerender-on-an-array-state-update)

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new array such that React understands it has changed. If you only push to the old viaList it will still hold that `viaList === previousViaList`. Instead create a new array, e.g. with the spread operator:

```js
  function addViaLocation() {
    const newElement = (
    <li key={uuidv4()}>
      <label className="form-label">
        Via Location
      </label>
    </li>)

    setViaList([...viaList, newElement]);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it...

I was doing the following (just longer):

```
setViaList([...viaList, <li>STUFF</li>])
```

I had to update the state array using a callback instead:

```
setViaList(viaList => [...viaList, <li>STUFF</li>])
```

Comment: even the first one is correct

Comment: The point is that `setViaList([...viaList, <li></li>])` works because with `[...viaList, <li></li>]` you create a **new array** (thus `[...viaList, <li></li>] !== viaList`). On the other side `viaList.push(<li></li>); setViaList(viaList)` won't work because you use the same array reference (`viaList === viaList`).

Answer (score 0):

```html
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

function BookingForm() {
  const [viaList, setViaList] = useState([]);

  function addViaLocation() {
    const arr = [...viaList];

    arr.push(
    <li key={uuidv4()}>
      <label className="form-label">
        Via Location
      </label>
    </li>)

    setViaList(arr);
  }

  return (
    <>
      <button onClick={addViaLocation} className="button-standard primary" type="button">
        Add Additional Location
      </button>
      <ul>{viaList.length > 0 && viaList.map(item => item)}</ul>
    </>
  );
}

export default BookingForm;
```

You can Create a shallow Copy of the Array by spreading the current state array  and then pushing the new data and update state with the shallow copy